# Center align an element that is 100% width

Tags: html, css

I need some help aligning an element.

Here's the layout I'm working with:

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.heading {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.file-input {
  display: block;
  border: 2px dashed #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h4 class="heading">7. Attachments</h4>
    <input type="file" class="file-input">
</div>
```

Is it at all possible to somehow center align the Choose File button along with the text inside the border without changing the HTML code?

**I can not change the HTML code. I can only work with what I have..**

**EDIT:** I just wanted to add that I want to maintain the border at `width: 100%`.

Comment: Are you trying to center it vertically or both horizontally and vertically?

Comment: So you want the "Choose File" button and text to be centered on the page with the dashed border still maintaining `width: 100%`?

Comment: @Tanner, correct.

Comment: @UXOL, just horizontally. It's already centered vertically because of the top & bottom padding.

Comment: I think that @DCR has got you set up in the remodel below.  Adding the wrapper should allow you to keep the width 100% and centered.

Answer (score 1):

This is as close as I can get.  You might be able to do this with grid

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.heading {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width:100%;
}

.file-input {
 
  border: 2px dashed #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left:35%;
  padding-right:35%;
  width: 30%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h4 class="heading">7. Attachments</h4>
    <input type="file" class="file-input">
</div>
```

Comment: You beat me to it ha ha!  Adding a wrapper should be the key to getting this button centered with the width at 100%.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
   <h4 class="heading">7. Attachments</h4>
   <div class="inputwrap">
      <input type="file" class="file-input">
   </div>
</div>

   .file-input {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 0;
   }
   .inputwrap {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 2px dashed #ddd;
   }
```